# And operator in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone guide me on how to quickly understand this logic in vba. I am currently debugging a code and it contains if conditions using AND operand like below.

```
if (a and b) <> 0 then
  do something
end if
```

a and be have numeric values assign to it and the comparison returns a numeric value. I just want to know how to read this kind of logic using an and operator. I am familiar if the condition might have been if (a > 5 and b < 5).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if `a` or `b` are numeric then if they are zero they default to `False`, otherwise to `True`.

Comment: See [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251591.aspx] . If both operands are numerics, `And` performs a bitwise comparison.

Answer (score 3):

It's doing a Bitwise comparison.  If `a` and `b` share any common bits on then `(a and b) <> 0` will return `TRUE`

Eg if `a` = `5` = `0101` and `b` = `6` = `0110` then `a and b` = `0100` = `4`

Answer (score 0):

Not having more of the code, this seems to be a comparison of two settings.

Bit based fields are often used to keep track of flags/settings.  While limited in number (depending on the size of integers in your architecture), it allows for quick manipulation and testing.

So, if `a` is `0101`, it holds several flags (bit based numbers start from the right)

```
Flag 1 (1st bit) = On
Flag 2 (2nd bit) = Off
Flag 3 (3rd bit) = On
Flag 4 (4th bit) = Off
```

Assume you have another variable, `b`, which also hold flags

```
Flag 1 (1st bit) = Off (different than a)
Flag 2 (2nd bit) = Off
Flag 3 (3rd bit) = On
Flag 4 (4th bit) = On (different than a)
```

You can quickly compare them using bitwise operations:

```
if (a and b) = 0101 and 1100 = 0100 = common flags
if (a or b) = 0101 or 1100 = 1101 = all flags across both variable
```

Answer (score -2):

Although a and b are numeric, they are being used as Boolean because of the "and" comparison. If the numeric value is 0, then it will be converted to FALSE. Otherwise for any non-zero value it will be treated as TRUE

So the above condition will evaluate as TRUE only if both a and b are non-zero.

You can can actually assign a numeric value to a boolean to test this, e.g.

```
Sub test()
Dim a As Integer
Dim abool As Boolean

    a = 1
    abool = a
    MsgBox ("a:" & a & "    abool:" & abool)

End Sub
```

In the above example you will get "a:1  abool:True" as the result.

Comment: Not true.  `and` with integers does a bitwise comaprison